# Is there a formula that relates chlorine concentration, contact time, and iron?

Tags: water, well, chlorine

If I want to remove iron from my well water with a chlorine injector (injects based on flow) and a contact tank I know that iron removal will be based on contact time and amount of chlorine.  I am having my water tested to determine exactly how much iron is in the water, but is there a formula that relates contact time, iron removal, and chlorine concentration?

Comment: Are there instructions with the chlorine injector? I'll be they specify how to set it up.

Comment: I do not yet own a chlorine injector -- I'm looking to understand before purchasing.

Comment: I don't have a formula for you, but before you buy a contact tank, learn about ***baffle factor*** and how it affects the size of the contact tank you need, i.e., you need a much bigger tank to achieve a given contact time if it has a low baffle factor. If you're relying on a 20 minute contact time to produce filterable particles, a tank with a low baffle factor would have to be enormous.

Comment: It would be handy to have specified that in your question.

Comment: It's well water so there should already be a chemical-free backwashing filter and a regenerating softener. If those aren't doing it for you then it's time to look at adding chlorine. At our lake house in MI we can't water the lawn w/o putting red all over the walls, so it's a pretty high concentration there. But with a softener and a filter it doesn't taste like blood anymore (and salty, so still can't water the lawn). However it also sucks to wash your hands; I hate it.